# GM8 Pro - 3d - draw text at topleft of screen

Tags: game-maker

folks

just created a nice little stars sim in Game Maker Studio 8 Pro (using just the simple d3d functions), and I want to add some text to the top left of the screen...

everything looks great, and works as expected, except for the text.  i've searched google, youtube, stackexchange, and MANY gml forums, and I just can't find what i'm looking for.  or, if i have found it, i a) didn't know it, or b) didn't get it right.  either way, i'm kinda stuck.

how do i draw some static text in the top left corner of the projection?

i've put the following code into my draw event of my camera object before and after setting the projection:

```
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_text(0, 0, "hello");
```

neither works as i had hoped....i want to create a simple "debug" panel.

if you wanna see my code, let me know, i'll post it.  i haven't posted my code now because I don't believe it's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the GUI draw event that might work.
Just place your draw_text in there.
Gamemaker studios supports this not Gamemaker 8 or below...
Is Gamemaker Studios 8 a thing???

Comment: ya, that did the trick, Daedric.  i appreciate everyone's input!  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the trick I used for 2D drawing was this:

---

The `x` and `y` coördinates used by the draw functions aren't for the window, but for the room. This makes it convenient to draw things like sprites: you can just draw at a character's x or y position, But it means that if you draw at 0,0 and the window's top-left corner is currently at 100,100 then what you draw won't show up.

The trick is to find out where the view is (assuming you only have one) with `view_xview[0]` and `view_yview[0]`, so:

```
draw_set_color(c_white);
draw_text(view_xview[0] + view_yview[0] + 0, 0, "hello");
```

---

I don't know if this will work for 3D though.